# Open quote is expected for attribute "android:showAsAction" associated with an element type "item"

Tags: android

this error is shown when binding menu xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@id/menu_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    **at here show this error**android:showAsAction=["ifRoom" | "never" | "withText" | "always" | "collapseActionView"]
    android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enclosing the whole of the `showAsAction` value in quotes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@id/menu_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|never|withText|always|collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably copy-paste the text from a book or something like that. Is not the same quote:

```
height=”fill_parent”
height="fill_parent"
```